# How can I terminate (without raising another exception) my python script while handling an exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my python3 script, I am calling an external program with the `subprocess` module. When the called program exits with a non-zero status code, a `CalledProcessError` is thrown. In that case I print an error message and want to terminate the script in the exception handler.

My problem is, that `exit()` works by throwing a `SystemExit` exception itself, so I end up with:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

The script looks similar to this:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(["program"])
    return output
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
    print("program returned non-zero exit status", file=sys.stderr)
    exit(error.returncode)
```

How can I terminate the script without throwing an exception?

Comment: Why are you passing the error.returncode to exit() if you don't want it to propagate?

Comment: @mdurant I want to signal the exit code to the shell (which called this script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`os._exit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit) Would allow you to quit without raising an exception, but I wouldn't recommend that approach, because it exits ungracefully; no cleanup will be done.

You could also tweak your logic of `subprocess` a bit, so that `sys.exit` gets called outside of the `except` block:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(["programm"])
    return output
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
    print("programm returned non-zero exit status", file=sys.stderr)
    returncode = error.returncode
exit(returncode)  # You'll only reach this if an exception occurred.
```

That way you shouldn't get a traceback (though I actually can't reproduce getting the message you get, even if I leave the `exit` inside the `except` block).

Comment: That way I don't get a `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`, but I get a traceback nonetheless (from `exit()`), but I guess that's what `exit()` does - raising `SystemExit`.

Comment: @WilhelmSchuster What environment are you executing this code in? I don't normally see a traceback for a call to `exit` or `sys.exit`.

Comment: I was running it via `python3 -i script.py` (makes debugging easier). You're right, with `python3 script.py` no traceback is shown. Thanks.